# Maximum subset which has no sum of two divisible by K

Tags: c++, algorithm, formula

I am given the set {1, 2, 3, ... ,N}. I have to find the maximum size of a subset of the given set so that the sum of any 2 numbers from the subset is not divisible by a given number K. N and K can be up to 2*10^9 so i need a very fast algorithm. I only came up with an algorithm of complexity O(K), which is slow.

Comment: Is the input set always consecutive numbers from 1 through N?

Comment: Yes the input contains just the numbers N and K, which means i have in the set the numbers {1,2,3,4, ...,N}.

Comment: Maximum size in terms of subset cardinality or sum of the subset's values? And do you only need the size or the actual subset?

Answer (score 5):

first calculate all of the set elements mod k.and solve simple problem:
find the maximum size of a subset of the given set so that the sum of any 2 numbers from the subset is not equal by a given number K.
i divide this set to two sets (i and k-i) that you can not choose set(i) and set(k-i) Simultaneously.

```
int myset[]
int modclass[k]

for(int i=0; i< size of myset ;i++)
{
    modclass[(myset[i] mod k)] ++;
}
```

choose

```
for(int i=0; i< k/2 ;i++)
{ 
    if (modclass[i] > modclass[k-i])
    {
        choose all of the set elements that the element mod k equal i
    }
    else
    {
        choose all of the set elements that the element mod k equal k-i
    }
}
```

finally you can add one element from that the element mod k equal 0 or k/2.

this solution with an algorithm of complexity O(K).

you can improve this idea with dynamic array:

```
for(int i=0; i< size of myset ;i++)
{
    x= myset[i] mod k;
    set=false;
    for(int j=0; j< size of newset ;j++)
    {
        if(newset[j][1]==x or newset[j][2]==x)
        {
            if (x < k/2)
            {
                newset[j][1]++;
                set=true;
            }
            else
            {
                newset[j][2]++;
                set=true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(set==false)
    {
        if (x < k/2)
        {
            newset.add(1,0);
        }
        else
        {
            newset.add(0,1);
        }
    }
}
```

now you can choose with an algorithm of complexity O(myset.count).and your algorithm is more than  O(myset.count) because you need O(myset.count) for read your set.
complexity of this solution is  O(myset.count^2),that you can choose algorithm depended your input.with compare between  O(myset.count^2) and o(k).
and for better solution you can sort myset based on mod k.

Comment: This looks like a solution to the general problem of an arbitrary set of natural numbers. Given the information that the set is the numbers 1 through N, I believe there should be an O(1) solution based on calculations involving only N and K.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that the set of numbers is always 1 through N for some N.

Consider the first N-(N mod K) numbers. The form floor(N/K) sequences of K consecutive numbers, with reductions mod K from 0 through K-1. For each group, floor(K/2) have to be dropped for having a reduction mod K that is the negation mod K of another subset of floor(K/2). You can keep ceiling(K/2) from each set of K consecutive numbers.

Now consider the remaining N mod K numbers. They have reductions mod K starting at 1. I have not worked out the exact limits, but if N mod K is less than about K/2 you will be able to keep all of them. If not, you will be able to keep about the first ceiling(K/2) of them.

==========================================================================

I believe the concept here is correct, but I have not yet worked out all the details.

==========================================================================

Here is my analysis of the problem and answer. In what follows |x| is floor(x). This solution is similar to the one in @Constantine's answer, but differs in a few cases.

Consider the first K*|N/K| elements. They consist of |N/K| repeats of the reductions modulo K.

In general, we can include |N/K| elements that are k modulo K subject to the following limits:

If (k+k)%K is zero, we can include only one element that is k modulo K. That is the case for k=0 and k=(K/2)%K, which can only happen for even K.

That means we get |N/K| * |(K-1)/2| elements from the repeats.

We need to correct for the omitted elements. If N >= K we need to add 1 for the 0 mod K elements. If K is even and N>=K/2 we also need to add 1 for the (K/2)%K elements.

Finally, if M(N)!=0 we need to add a partial or complete copy of the repeat elements, min(N%K,|(K-1)/2|).

The final formula is:

```
|N/K| * |(K-1)/2| +
(N>=K ? 1 : 0) +
((N>=K/2 && (K%2)==0) ? 1 : 0) +
min(N%K,|(K-1)/2|)
```

This differs from @Constantine's version in some cases involving even K. For example, consider N=4, K=6. The correct answer is 3, the size of the set {1, 2, 3}. @Constantine's formula gives |(6-1)/2| = |5/2| = 2. The formula above gets 0 for each of the first two lines, 1 from the third line, and 2 from the final line, giving the correct answer.

Comment: i can not think about it wholly.but i guess your solution correctly and i vote up it,but your solution can not send elements to output:D

Comment: @amink Thanks for the upvote. The question says "find the maximum size of a subset", not "find the largest subset", so I was not trying to generate the subset, only calculate its size. The question also asked for a fast solution. My solution is O(1). Any solution that generates the set is \Omega(N) for K>1.

Answer (score 3):

formula is

```
|N/K| * |(K-1)/2| + ost 

ost =
if n<k:
  ost =0
else if n%k ==0 :
  ost =1    
else if n%k < |(K-1)/2| :
  ost = n%k
else:
  ost = |(K-1)/2|
```

where |a/b| 
for example |9/2| = 4     |7/2| = 3

example n = 30 , k =7 ;

1  2  3  4  5  6  7
8  9  10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30

1 2 3 |4| 5 6 7. - is first line .
 8 9 10 |11| 12 13 14 - second line 
if we getting first 3 number in each line we may get size of this subset. also we may adding one number from ( 7 14 28)

getting first 3 number (1 2 3) is a number |(k-1)/2|  . 
a number of  this line is |n/k| .
  if there is not residue we may add one number (for example last number).
 if residue < |(k-1)/2| we get all number in last line 
else getting |(K-1)/2|.

thanks for exception case.
ost = 0 if k>n

Comment: I think the formula is correct. The answer would be much better with some explanation.

Comment: After further thought, it seems to me that it fails to account for including one copy of K/2 if K is even. For example, it gives answer 2 for N=4, K=6. The correct answer is 3, the size of {1, 2, 3}. See my answer for my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

```
n,k=(raw_input().split(' '))
n=int(n)
k=int(k)
l=[0 for x in range(k)]
d=[int(x) for x in raw_input().split(' ')]
flag=0
for x in d:
   l[x%k]=l[x%k]+1

sum=0

if l[0]!=0:
    sum+=1 
if (k%2==0):
    sum+=1


if k==1:
    print 1
elif k==2:
    print 2 
else:       
    i=1
    j=k-1
    while i<j:
        sum=sum+(l[i] if l[i]>=l[j] else l[j])
        i=i+1
        j=j-1
     print sum
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation as to why this is a good fit for the question?

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

### This is explanation to ABRAR TYAGI and amin k's solution.

The approach to this solution is:

- Create an array L with K buckets and group all the elements from the 
  input array D into the K buckets. Each bucket L[i] contains D's elements such that ( element % K ) = i.
- All the elements that are individually divisible by K are in L[0]. So
  only one of these elements (if any) can belong in our final (maximal)
  subset. Sum of any two of these elements is divisible by K.
- If we add an element from L[i] to an element in L[K-i] then the sum is divisible by K. Hence we can add elements from only one of these buckets to
  our final set. We pick the largest    bucket.

Code:
d is the array containing the initial set of numbers of size n. The    goal of this code is to find the count of the largest subset of d    such that the sum of no two integers is divisible by 2.

l is an array that will contain k integers. The idea is to reduce each (element) in array d to (element % k) and save the frequency of their occurrences in array l.

For example, l[1] contains the frequency of all elements % k = 1

We know that 1 + (k-1) % k = 0 so either l[1] or l[k-1] have to be discarded to meet the criteria that sum of no two numbers % k should be 0.

But as we need the largest subset of d, we choose the larger of l[1] and l[k-1]

We loop through array l such that for (i=1; i<=k/2 && i < k-i; i++) and do the above step.

There are two outliers. The sum of any two numbers in the l[0] group % k = 0. So add 1 if l[0] is non-zero.

if k is even, the loop does not handle i=k/2, and using the same logic as above increment the count by one.

Comment: This is explanation to @ABRAR TYAGI and amin k's solutions.