# Find Non Divisible subset

Tags: java, logic

Given a set S, of n  distinct integers, print the size of a maximal subset S', of S where the sum of any 2 numbers in S' are not evenly divisible by k.
n= number of items in an array, k = number to be divided by.
S = array

```
    eg: Input from STDIN
   10 5
   770528134 663501748 384261537 800309024 103668401 538539662 385488901   101262949 557792122 46058493

    eg: Input from STDIN
    4 3
    1 7 2 4

    Explanation :

    1+7 = 8 : 8 is not evenly divisible
    1+4 = 5 : 5 is not evenly divisible
    7+4 = 11: 11 is not evenly divisible

    1+2 = 3
    2+4 =6
    2+7 = 9

    Those are divisible by 3, so the subset S' = {1,7,4) of size 3.
```

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            int n = in.nextInt();

            int k = in.nextInt();

            long arr[] = new long[n];

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                arr[i] = in.nextInt();
            }


            final Set<Long> subset = new LinkedHashSet<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {

                    long sum = arr[i] + arr[j];

                    if (sum % k != 0) {

                        subset.add(arr[i]);
                        subset.add(arr[j]);
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(subset.size());
        }
```

I am getting a right answer for second input ie. 3. However, I am getting 9 for first input, which I am expecting to spit out 6.

Comment: `for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)` becomes `for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) if (i != j)`

Comment: I have fixed the question. I apologize for that.

Comment: Made some changes to the code. Fixed another possible defect.

Comment: @KenY-N: Why should j start with 0? when i =0, I already traverse through the loop for that element, then changing j =0, I will be going through the element again. Won't it take more computation?

Comment: ahh. Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001634/maximum-subset-which-has-no-sum-of-two-divisible-by-k. However, there was no right answer check mark on any solution.

Comment: @user3369719, your algorithm will print 3 for the next input: '3 2' '1 2 4'

Comment: @user3707125: hmm. you are right. The explanation they gave for this question is not clear to me now.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot readily follow the idea in your algorithm. What makes you think that it should work?

Instead here’s another idea. The rule was that two elements `i` and `j` from the base set cannot both go into the subset if `(i + j) % k == 0`. Assuming i and j are both positive, this is the same as `(i % k == 0 && j % k == 0) || i % k + j % k == k`. So I want to group the elements by their remainder modulus k. For any two such groups with remainders `r` and `k - r` (1 <= r < k) I can safely add one group to the subset, and I will want to add the larger of the two. I can additionally add one element from the group with remainder 0 (not two, since their sum will be divisible by k). If k is even, I can also add just one element from the group with remainder k / 2.

Edit: code is probably more precise, so here goes:

```
// assume all elements > 0
static Set<Integer> findLargestSubset(int k, int... baseSetElements) {
    List<Integer> asList = IntStream.of(baseSetElements).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Set<Integer> baseSet = new HashSet<Integer>(asList);
    int n = baseSet.size();

    // group elements from set by their remainder modulus k
    List<List<Integer>> elementsByModulus = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int ix = 0; ix < k; ix++) {
        elementsByModulus.add(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    for (int i : baseSet) {
        if (i <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + i);
        }
        elementsByModulus.get(i % k).add(i);
    }
    Set<Integer> largestSubset = new HashSet<>(n);
    for (int remainder = 1; remainder < (k + 1) / 2; remainder++) {
        List<Integer> groupR = elementsByModulus.get(remainder);
        List<Integer> groupKMinusR = elementsByModulus.get(k - remainder);
        // add larger group to result
        if (groupR.size() > groupKMinusR.size()) {
            largestSubset.addAll(groupR);
        } else {
            largestSubset.addAll(groupKMinusR);
        }
    }
    // add one element with remainder 0 if any
    if (!elementsByModulus.get(0).isEmpty()) {
        largestSubset.add(elementsByModulus.get(0).get(0));
    }
    // if k is even, add one element with remainder k / 2 if any
    if (k % 2 == 0 && !elementsByModulus.get(k / 2).isEmpty()) {
        largestSubset.add(elementsByModulus.get(k / 2).get(0));
    }
    return largestSubset;
}
```

For the first example in your question this gives `[800309024, 557792122, 384261537, 538539662, 770528134, 101262949]`, hence size 6.